# Tensorboard what-if tool

Tags: tensorboard

I am using the tensorboard new function : what-if tool. but do now know how to use it,should I add some code in my PY file in order to use this tool? can anybody share me a demo how to use it? I can find the What-if option in the tensorborad, but just do not know how to set it as required in the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOaDI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To use it in Tensorboard,  you need to serve your model through a TensorFlow Serving model server, then provide the hostname and port in the inference address field and the model name used by TF serving in the model name field. Then provide a path to some tensorflow example protos on disk as input to the model, as described here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/tree/master/tensorboard/plugins/interactive_inference#what-do-i-need-to-use-it-in-tensorboard

Another option in to use the what-if tool inside a colab or jupyter notebook, as shown here: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/plugins/interactive_inference/What_If_Tool_Notebook_Usage.ipynb

Documentation on how to use the tool inside of a notebook can be found here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/tree/master/tensorboard/plugins/interactive_inference#notebook-mode-details

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Johan as you predicted 4 years ago, these links are now broken, and so too is this answer.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out our Learning Interpretability Tool (LIT) instead of the What-If Tool, as LIT is still being actively developed.

https://pair-code.github.io/lit/
https://github.com/pair-code/lit